# How to navigate on specific screen from route directory in react native?

Tags: react-native, routes, react-navigation

I am using react switch navigator from react-navigation library. I create a separate file router.js and call in my App.js. Now i am using react-native-firebase and from the app.js i need to navigate to specific screen. If anyone having an idea then please let me know here is my code:

App.js:

```
import Router from "./src/Router";
class App extends Component<Props> {
render() {
    return (
      <Router />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Router.js

```
const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    InitialScreen: {
        screen: InitialScreen
    },
    Login: {
        screen: Login
    },
    Forgot: {
        screen: Forgot
    },
    SuccessMessage: {
        screen: SuccessMessage
    },
    App: AppStackDelivery,
    AppR: AppStackRecipient,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'InitialScreen'
});

const Router = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);

export default Router;
```

From the push notification i am receiving id and i need to navigate to detail screen but i don't get anything to my router or initial screen please anyone having an idea then please share.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Deep link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html). And go to the path you want in `onNotification`.

**Example**

```js
handleNotification () {
    const  path  = "chat/Eric";
    const prefix = Platform.OS === 'android' 
                     ? 'myapp://myapp/'
                     : 'myapp://'
    const url = `${prefix}${path}`;

        Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => console.error(err));
        firebase.messaging().setBadgeNumber(0);
  }
```

Comment: I used global variables here instead of doing this tricky method.

Comment: How do you plan to move to a global variable?

Comment: I updated my global variable and it can access anywhere from app.

Comment: One more thing how do I use drawer navigator in my above router do you any idea? I am totally stuck here.